# IOS Run custom shell script 'embed pods framework' file not found error

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am getting an error when building my app after i removed reference to a framework i added incorrectly. i am new to ios and cocoapods

`/Users/MyMac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ewxrexwuczochyctnqvlyusrtvvy/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Script-5874133373474758EEC76CFD.sh: line 2: /Users/MyMac/Documents/MyApp/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MyApp/Pods-MyApp-frameworks.sh: No such file or directory`

I am aware that the file and directory don't exist and that is the way it should be but where is it finding the reference to this file so i can remove it and be rid of the error.

**I have checked the following:**

- Linked Frameworks andLibraries under the general tab of my project
- The frameworks group in the project
- framework search paths under build settings tab
- i have also run pod update after removing it from the pod file

How can i fix this?

**Edit**
back story

I was trying to add the framework https://github.com/Alliants/ALAccordion . in the instruction it said to use

```
# Podfile
target 'My Target' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod "ALAccordion"
end
```

so i added MyApp where my Target is and it created a framework named Pods-MyApp which i cant remove completely.

hope this helps

Comment: When you run `pod install`, is the result successful?

Comment: yes but the file in question Pods-MyApp is not in the pod file any more as it was put in in error. see edit (in about a minute)

Comment: It would be tough to get this specifically without a screenshare but I've got a solution anyway, will post shortly :)

Comment: I can appreciate that. all attempts welcome

Comment: If it is not solved yet , you can check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dS6UwD51EGg .

Comment: in my case, I just removed space from the project root folder name and it starts working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cocoapods wrote a tool to completely deintegrate all of this stuff from your project so it goes back to running standalone. It sounds like you had an issue adding the correct target, so use this:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate

Then try again so you can at least start from good ground. Hope this helps!

Comment: It appears to have worked. don't have time to fully test it until tomorrow. so i will accept your answer then if all still seams well then. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It happened with a prerelease version of Cocoapods `1.2.0.beta.1`, by reverting to stable version and running `pod install`, then clean build, it worked.

Answer (score -1):

why

> use_frameworks!

after

> target ... do

here is example

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'XXX' do
  pod 'RealmSwift'
end

target 'XXXTests' do
  pod 'RealmSwift'
end
```

Comment: sorry this did not help. to be clear the framework in question is not in the podfile any more as it is not in the project and not needed. also what is the purpose of the line you suggested?

Comment: the Edit to the question i made  might help

Comment: If you run the command pod init, it will itself put the 'use_frameworks! after target 'xxx' do